# Can't bind scope variable to array key?

Tags: angularjs

Why is this happening?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="address"/>

app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.location = {address: $scope.address};
    $scope.getFood = function(){
        console.log($scope.location);
        console.log($scope.address)
    };
```

Logging $scope.location gives

```
Object {address: undefined}
```

When I log $scope.address, it gives me the value.

Comment: if you want address to be part of the location then just bind it to `location.address` instead of `address`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could set `$scope.location = {address: null};` 
and then in your markup `<input type="text" ng-model="location.address"/>`